# Merge duplicate keys in multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a script that loops through a bunch of data collected from database tables. I've read other similar posts on StackOverflow about merging duplicate array keys, but none of them seem to work for me. Using the code below, I'm building all of the compiled data into an array:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM '.$qstTable.' WHERE '.$type.'_qst_id = '.$answer['answer_qst'];
$result = $db->sql_query($sql);
$q = $db->sql_fetchrow($result);
$db->sql_freeresult($result);

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM '.$catTable.' WHERE '.$type.'_cat_clean = "'.$q[$type.'_qst_cat'].'"';
$result = $db->sql_query($sql);
$cat = $db->sql_fetchrow($result);
$db->sql_freeresult($result);

$daField = $cat[$type.'_cat_name'];

if(count($allQsts)){
    if(array_key_exists($daField, $allQsts)){
        $daData = array(
            'question' => array(
                'id' => $q[$type.'_qst_id'],
                'qst' => $q[$type.'_qst_qst'],
            ),
            'answer' => array(
                'id' => $answer['answer_id'],
                'type' => $answer['answer_input'],
                'content' => $answer['answer_content'],
                'q_type' => $type,
            )
        );
        array_push($allQsts[$daField], $daData);
    }else{
        $allQsts[$cat[$type.'_cat_name']][] = array(
            'question' => array(
                'id' => $q[$type.'_qst_id'],
                'qst' => $q[$type.'_qst_qst'],
            ),
            'answer' => array(
                'id' => $answer['answer_id'],
                'type' => $answer['answer_input'],
                'content' => $answer['answer_content'],
                'q_type' => $type,
            )
        );
    }
}else{
    $allQsts[$cat[$type.'_cat_name']][] = array(
        'question' => array(
            'id' => $q[$type.'_qst_id'],
            'qst' => $q[$type.'_qst_qst'],
        ),
        'answer' => array(
            'id' => $answer['answer_id'],
            'type' => $answer['answer_input'],
            'content' => $answer['answer_content'],
            'q_type' => $type,
        )
    );
}
```

And this is how my array turns out looking when it's all processed:

```
Array ( 
    [Ancestry] => Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( 
            [question] => Array ( 
                [id] => 1 
                [qst] => Has your family always lived in this country? Where did your family come from? How did they come here? 
            ) 
            [answer] => Array ( 
                [id] => 28 
                [type] => text 
                [content] => idk 
                [q_type] => life 
            ) 
        ) 
    ) 
) 
Array ( 
    [High School] => Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( 
            [question] => Array ( 
                [id] => 158 
                [qst] => Who were your best friends in high school? Were they the same ones from grade school? Do you still keep in touch with them? 
            ) 
            [answer] => Array ( 
                [id] => 30 
                [type] => video 
                [content] => v-0bd3d270-2f24-0132-cd89-12313914f10b 
                [q_type] => life 
            ) 
        ) 
    ) 
)
Array ( 
    [High School] => Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( 
            [question] => Array ( 
                [id] => 124 
                [qst] => What year did you start high school? What high school did you go to? Did you like it? Did you ever wish you would've gone to a different high school? 
            ) 
            [answer] => Array ( 
                [id] => 36 
                [type] => text 
                [content] => Started HS in 1987 
                [q_type] => life 
            ) 
        ) 
    ) 
) 
Array ( 
    [Young Adult] => Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( 
            [question] => Array ( 
                [id] => 213 
                [qst] => As a young adult did you stay in the same town as your friends or did you move to a new place and had to make new friends? 
            ) 
            [answer] => Array ( 
                [id] => 39 
                [type] => video 
                [content] => v-7d59df50-3bda-0132-cda7-12313914f10b 
                [q_type] => life 
            ) 
        ) 
    ) 
) 
Array ( 
    [Young Adult] => Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( 
            [question] => Array ( 
                [id] => 207 
                [qst] => After high school - did you go to college, join the miltary, or did you get a job? 
            ) 
            [answer] => Array ( 
                [id] => 40 
                [type] => text 
                [content] => went to college at ASU 
                [q_type] => life 
            ) 
        ) 
    ) 
) 
Array ( 
    [Multiple Sclerosis] => Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( 
            [question] => Array ( 
                [id] => 1278 
                [qst] => Do you know of any potential new drugs or treatments that are in development to treat multiple sclerosis? Are you optomistic? 
            ) 
            [answer] => Array ( 
                [id] => 33 
                [type] => text 
                [content] => vg hjc 
                [q_type] => pack 
            ) 
        ) 
    ) 
)
```

However, What I would like to do is combine nodes in the array that already exist, like so:

```
Array ( 
    [Ancestry] => Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( 
            [question] => Array ( 
                [id] => 1 
                [qst] => Has your family always lived in this country? Where did your family come from? How did they come here? 
            ) 
            [answer] => Array ( 
                [id] => 28 
                [type] => text 
                [content] => idk 
                [q_type] => life 
            ) 
        ) 
    ) 
) 
Array ( 
    [High School] => Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( 
            [question] => Array ( 
                [id] => 158 
                [qst] => Who were your best friends in high school? Were they the same ones from grade school? Do you still keep in touch with them? 
            ) 
            [answer] => Array ( 
                [id] => 30 
                [type] => video 
                [content] => v-0bd3d270-2f24-0132-cd89-12313914f10b 
                [q_type] => life 
            ) 
        ) 
        [1] => Array ( 
            [question] => Array ( 
                [id] => 124 
                [qst] => What year did you start high school? What high school did you go to? Did you like it? Did you ever wish you would've gone to a different high school? 
            ) 
            [answer] => Array ( 
                [id] => 36 
                [type] => text 
                [content] => Started HS in 1987 
                [q_type] => life 
            ) 
        ) 
    ) 
)
Array ( 
    [Young Adult] => Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( 
            [question] => Array ( 
                [id] => 213 
                [qst] => As a young adult did you stay in the same town as your friends or did you move to a new place and had to make new friends? 
            ) 
            [answer] => Array ( 
                [id] => 39 
                [type] => video 
                [content] => v-7d59df50-3bda-0132-cda7-12313914f10b 
                [q_type] => life 
            ) 
        )
        [1] => Array ( 
            [question] => Array ( 
                [id] => 207 
                [qst] => After high school - did you go to college, join the miltary, or did you get a job? 
            ) 
            [answer] => Array ( 
                [id] => 40 
                [type] => text 
                [content] => went to college at ASU 
                [q_type] => life 
            ) 
        ) 
    ) 
)
Array ( 
    [Multiple Sclerosis] => Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( 
            [question] => Array ( 
                [id] => 1278 
                [qst] => Do you know of any potential new drugs or treatments that are in development to treat multiple sclerosis? Are you optomistic? 
            ) 
            [answer] => Array ( 
                [id] => 33 
                [type] => text 
                [content] => vg hjc 
                [q_type] => pack 
            ) 
        ) 
    ) 
)
```

How can I modify the code above to do this?

**EDIT** - Updating to include some of the code I've tried to compress the array:
After the full `$allQsts` array is created, I looped it through this and tested the output, but each entry was duplicated even more.

```
$sortedIt = array();
foreach($allQsts as $m => $n){
    if(!isset($sortedIt[$m])){
        $sortedIt[$m] = array();
    }
    $sortedIt[$m] = $n;
}
```

I've also been playing around with `array_merge_recursive` but have yet to get anywhere close.

Comment: If you've read a few posts, surely you must have tried some of the answers? In other words, what have you tried?

Comment: Btw, your output shows 6 arrays and not a single array; how did you get that output?

Comment: @Ja͢ck I've updated the post to show some code I've tried. As for the output, it's probably because of the loop the code resides in. It's a ridiculously complex loop structure, probably poorly designed, but also the only way I could get the whole thing to work.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is run in a loop and `$allQsts` points to the same array each time, you can simplify the code drastically:

```
$daField = $cat[$type.'_cat_name'];
$daData = array(
    'question' => array(
        'id' => $q[$type.'_qst_id'],
        'qst' => $q[$type.'_qst_qst'],
    ),
    'answer' => array(
        'id' => $answer['answer_id'],
        'type' => $answer['answer_input'],
        'content' => $answer['answer_content'],
        'q_type' => $type,
    )
);

if (array_key_exists($daField, $allQsts)) {
    $allQsts[$daField][] = $daData;
} else {
    $allQsts[$daField] = array($daData);
}
```

This by itself should be enough to get the desired data structure.

Comment: It seems to partially work, but at the end of one of the loops I unset `$allQsts` because I was having issues with it doubling, then tripling, etc, data as it went through the loop. If you would be willing, I can post the whole script on pastebin or something so you can take a look. Like I said, it's complex and convoluted.

Comment: @chaoskreator You'd have to figure out first why it's doubling and tripling.